# How to I extract the first int from a slice object

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a slice object and I wanted to extract the first int from it.  This object type seems read only/immutable. Using python 2.7

```
foo = slice(22,24)

foo
Out[44]: slice(22, 24, None)

foo[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-d8976430aff2> in <module>()
----> 1 foo[0]

TypeError: 'slice' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I'm trying to access the 22 as an int to use for location indexing later. Does anyone have any ideas.
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer the section [slice(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice), it mentions

> Slice objects have read-only data attributes start, stop and step
>   which merely return the argument values (or their default).

```
>>> foo = slice(22,24)
>>> foo.start
22
```

Comment: @Lonewolf: Feel free to accept the answer if you think its helpful.